# What is the inverse of the Position function?

Tags: list-manipulation, built-in-symbols, inverse

What is the inverse of the `Position`?

I have an array which contains the positions of elements and I want a function which returns an List which contains 1 where those elements are and 0 elsewhere. For example, the List `{1, 5}` would return `{1,0,0,0,1}` or `{2,1,4}` would return `{1,1,0,1}`. Additional arguments might need to be supplied for length etc. (Technically, this function is a inverse of restricted version of the Position function)

I realize that I could do with `Table` but it seems like this would be a common enough process that there would be a built in function for this. However, I have not been able to find it in the documentation.

Comment: Am I missing something? `Reverse[IntegerDigits[Tr[2^(#-1)],2]]&` s/b quite efficient. Add the length argument to `IntegerDigits` if you want a mask matching some arbitrary length.

Comment: I would not call that the inverse of `Position` ... the true inverse of `Position`, i.e. a function that takes `Position`'s output and returns its input, is `Extract`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know that you can do it in a single command. But it's easy enough to do in two. Say your list is `list={2,1,4};`

```
x = ConstantArray[0, Max[list]];
x[[list]] = 1;

x
{1, 1, 0, 1}
```

Effectively, `Part` (or the shortcut [[ ]]) acts as an approximate inverse of `Position`.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it is the fastest in my limited testing

Comment: @TheSquareCow This solution is silent about duplicates.  (Also, it is hard to believe it is fastest.  Can you post your tests?)

Comment: Yes, I would throw `DeleteDuplicates` at the list first before moving on.

Comment: Here are my tests: 
In[190]:= RepeatedTiming[(x = ConstantArray[0,Max[#]]; x[[#]] = 1; x)&[{2,1,4}], 20]
Out[190]= {6.5*10^-6,{1,1,0,1}}

        
In[191]:= RepeatedTiming[(Normal@SparseArray[Thread[#->1]])&[{2,1,4}], 20]
Out[191]= {0.00002,{1,1,0,1}}         

       
In[192]:= RepeatedTiming[(Rest@BinCounts[#])&[{2,1,4}], 20]
Out[192]= {0.00032,{1,1,0,1}}

In[193]:= RepeatedTiming[Reverse[IntegerDigits[Tr[2^(#-1)],2]]&[{2,1,4}], 20]
Out[193]= {0.00001,{1,1,0,1}}

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I couldn't get the newlines inside a comment box to work correctly.

Answer (score 8):

```
Normal@SparseArray[Thread[{1, 5} -> 1]]
(*  {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}  *)

Normal@SparseArray[Thread[{2, 1, 4} -> 1]]
(*  {1, 1, 0, 1}  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {2, 1, 5};
Normal@SparseArray[Thread[list -> 1]]
```

or

```
dat = ConstantArray[0, Max@list];
dat[[{2, 1, 5}]] = 1;
dat
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In[253]:= Rest@BinCounts[{1, 5}]

Out[253]= {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}

In[254]:= Rest@BinCounts[{2, 1, 4}]

Out[254]= {1, 1, 0, 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `ReplaceAt` (since V 13.1)

```
list = {1, 5};

ReplaceAt[Table[0, Max @ list], _ :> 1, List /@ list]
```

{1, 0, 0, 0, 1}

With `ReplacePart`

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 6};

ReplacePart[Table[0, Max @ list], Thread[list -> 1]]
```

{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = x |-> Array[Boole @ MemberQ[#] @ x &, Max @ x];
```

***Examples:***

```
{#, f @ #} & /@ {{2, 1, 5}, {2, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 5}}
```

| position | f @ position |
| --- | --- |
| {2, 1, 5} | {1, 1, 0, 0, 1} |
| {2, 1, 2, 4} | {1, 1, 0, 1} |
| {1, 5} | {1, 0, 0, 0, 1} |

Answer (score 1):

```
f[pos_List] := 
 MapAt[# + 1 &, ConstantArray[0, Max[pos]], List /@ Union@pos]
```

or

```
g[pos_List] := Module[{temp = Max[pos] - # & /@ Union@pos},
  2^temp // Total // IntegerDigits[#, 2] &
  ]
```

---

*Usage:*

```
testcases = {{2, 1, 5}, {2, 1, 2, 4}, {1, 5}}

f /@ testcases
g /@ testcases
```

---

*Result:*

> {{1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `ReplaceAll`:

```
f = Range@Max[#] /. Catenate[Thread /@ {Complement[Range@Max[#], #] -> 0, # -> 1}] &;

f@{1, 5}

(*{1, 0, 0, 0, 1}*)

f@{2, 1, 4}

(*{1, 1, 0, 1}*)
```